# Camera preview is blurred in samsung galaxy grand but it is good in samsung s3

Tags: android, android-camera

Hey I just started a program for camera preview the code is working fine
But in my device(Samsung galaxy Grand) the camera is slightly blurred but when I run that in another device(Samsung S3) the camera quality fine is there any wrong with my code?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.practise.camera;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat; 
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
public Camera mCamera;
boolean mPreviewRunning;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
     mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
     mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
     mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


 }

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        if (mPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        mCamera.setParameters(p);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(arg0);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = true;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = false;
    mCamera.release();
}

Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {
    }
};



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <SurfaceView 
    android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Where's the problem with the code... Apart from the two devices I didnt check it on any device

The result for camera preview is [image: Camera preview application]

But the inbuilt camera application is fine and it shows like [image: Inbuilt Phone camera application]

Comment: Even I checked with another camera preview application in the Samasung galaxy grand the result was same the preview is blurred... but in the camera inbuilt app the clarity is good.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to tell the camera to auto focus. Add something similar to this in your surfaceChanged routine.

```
// newer phones can be told to auto focus before taking the picture
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    if ( p.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE) ) {
        p.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    }
}

mCamera.setParameters(p);
mCamera.startPreview();
```

Comment: I figured out the problem, when I set the previewsize and picturesize that suits for the device it is working fine...